# Calculating time between 5a-1p or 530a-130p

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, date-time

I was wondering if it is possible for Excel to calculate time span if each time block is in `5a-1p` format in one cell. That way I could add the hours for each week without changing too much.

Sample data:

```
Name   Mon     Tues    Wed        Thur   Fri    Sat     Sun     Total Hours 

Bill   2a-10p  5a-1p   730a-330p  OFF    OFF    5p-12a  5a-10a
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why can't you just convert the time to 24 hour notation then just use basic subtraction.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate hours and minutes between two time periods?](http://superuser.com/questions/147675/how-to-calculate-hours-and-minutes-between-two-time-periods)

Comment: @Ramhound I think the issue is that the time spans are formatted as text, and calculating the length requires parsing the text first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following formula will give the hours in one day's time span. It works by parsing the text and reformatting the start and end times in a time format that Excel recognizes. Once that is done, it's a matter of subtraction and conversion of the result to hours.

```
=IF(B2="OFF",0,((IF(LEN(RIGHT(B2,LEN(B2)-FIND("-",B2)))>3,LEFT(RIGHT(B2,LEN(B2)-FIND("-",B2)),LEN(RIGHT(B2,LEN(B2)-FIND("-",B2)))-3)&":"&MID(RIGHT(B2,LEN(B2)-FIND("-",B2)),LEN(RIGHT(B2,LEN(B2)-FIND("-",B2)))-2,2),LEFT(RIGHT(B2,LEN(B2)-FIND("-",B2)),LEN(RIGHT(B2,LEN(B2)-FIND("-",B2)))-1))&" "&RIGHT(RIGHT(B2,LEN(B2)-FIND("-",B2)),1)&"m")-(IF(LEN(LEFT(B2,FIND("-",B2)-1))>3,LEFT(LEFT(B2,FIND("-",B2)-1),LEN(LEFT(B2,FIND("-",B2)-1))-3)&":"&MID(LEFT(B2,FIND("-",B2)-1),LEN(LEFT(B2,FIND("-",B2)-1))-2,2),LEFT(LEFT(B2,FIND("-",B2)-1),LEN(LEFT(B2,FIND("-",B2)-1))-1))&" "&RIGHT(LEFT(B2,FIND("-",B2)-1),1)&"m"))*24+IF(AND(MID(B2,FIND("-",B2)-1,1)="p",RIGHT(B2,1)="a"),24,0))
```

Breaking it down:

`RIGHT(B2,LEN(B2)-FIND("-",B2))` is the end time in your format.

`LEFT(B2,FIND("-",B2)-1)` is the start time in your format.

Replacing these values with `End` and `Start` will help clarify what the formula is doing.

```
=IF(B2="OFF",0,((IF(LEN(End)>3,LEFT(End,LEN(End)-3)&":"&MID(End,LEN(End)-2,2),LEFT(End,LEN(End)-1))&" "&RIGHT(End,1)&"m")-(IF(LEN(Start)>3,LEFT(Start,LEN(Start)-3)&":"&MID(Start,LEN(Start)-2,2),LEFT(Start,LEN(Start)-1))&" "&RIGHT(Start,1)&"m"))*24+IF(AND(MID(B2,FIND("-",B2)-1,1)="p",RIGHT(B2,1)="a"),24,0))
```

This basically says, return 0 if B2 is `OFF`.
Otherwise, format the time so Excel recognizes it as a time value.

To do this, first, check how many digits precede the letter (a or p) in the time.

If there are more than 2 digits, the time includes minutes, so it needs to be formatted with a colon between hour and minutes. Otherwise, do nothing.

Then, put a space between the numbers and the letter and stick an `m` after the letter (to make it `am` or `pm`).

Once this is done for each, subtract the start time from the end time.
This returns the fraction of a day in the time span, so convert it to hours by multiplying by 24.

In the case that the end time is AM and the start time is PM, this results in a negative number. To correct for that, the formula checks for this condition and adds 24 to the result if it is met.

Comment: Great formula, works like a charm. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a shorter version:

=IF(B2="OFF",0,ABS(MOD(24*MMULT(LARGE(IFERROR(0+REPLACE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(B2,"a",":00 AM"),"p",":00 PM"),"-",REPT(" ",99)),99*{0,1}+1,99)),{2;3},,":00"),0),{1,2}),{1;-1}),24)-24*(IFERROR(MMULT(FIND({"a","p"},B2),{-1;1})<0,0))))

Regards